# Performing a redirect after post request in request module

Tags: node.js, express

I am using MEAN stack in my development. This is the sample excerpt from the code which auto redirect client browser from the server side when using performing logout.

```
exports.signout = function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

Now, suppose that I am doing a post request using node request module, how is it possible to redirect user to home page via server side after post request succeed.

```
var requestValue = {
    url: 'abc.com/endpoint',
    method: 'post',
    json: true
};

request(requestValue, function(err, response, body) {
    if (body) {
        // redirect user to home page
    }
});
```

Comment: When are you calling `request(requestValue, function)` ? Is it independent of any `req` from client side ?

Comment: I am calling it in Passport JS deserializeUser function, in which the deserializerUser function suppose to be call for every request made by user from client side.